# jQuery isotope checkbox filter, if all uncheck show no item

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-isotope

This is regarding input checkbox for filtering jQuery isotope itemselector.

Refer to demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xUU99/3/), checkboxes are checked when the page is load. However I stumble upon the problem when all is unchecked by user, it will just show all `.items` instead of an empty container.

```
$checkboxes.change(function(){
    var filters = [];
    // get checked checkboxes values                
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
    filters.push( this.value );
    });
    // ['.red', '.blue'] -> '.red, .blue'
    filters = filters.join(', ');
    $container.isotope({ filter: filters });
});
```

Many thanks in advance, cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The isotope library is [working as intended](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#filter).

> filter - Setting a filter with show item elements that match the
>   selector, and hide elements that do not match.
>
> Values  '*' or '' (an empty string): **Shows all item elements**

If you do not want this behaviour, and instead want to not show any elements when every filter is selected, you should change the filter string to be something that does not exist e.g.

```
if(filters.length == 0){
    filters = 'purplemonkyeydishwasher';
}
else{
    filters = filters.join(', ');
}
$container.isotope({ filter: filters });
```

This will then have the behaviour you want. I [updated the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Danack/xUU99/4/) and it now hides all the elements when all the filters are selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
$container.isotope({ filter: ( filters == null || filters.length == 0 ) ? 'default' : filters });`
```

Where `default` is always unused. See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/G6LRL/

Comment: THANK YOU! ( btw: there is an ` at the final of your string )